Synapse spark streaming job starts consuming entire queue repeatedly
I've a spark streaming pipeline in Azure Synapse which is continuously listening to events. Its basically python code with read/write stream. The streaming was working fine when the events were consumed sequentially in a micro-batch. We split the pipeline in multiple with filtered query against the event hub. After that, the pipeline has been repeatedly starts from first event in the event hub after consuming all available events in event hubs. It somehow starts consuming from first event again once it processes all events. The streaming query is based on filtered set of events and each filtered set has separate checkpoint and separate pipeline. What could be the reason for this behavior and how to stop this from happening?
startingOffset: "earliest"
failOnDataLoss:False
Expecting the checkpoint to stay put after consuming all events and not restart from first available event while consuming only new events. Any pointers are appreciated.
